# Margin-left and position left give different values with the same percentage

Tags: css, css-position, margin

I have a div with:

```
 width:100%;
 max-width:100%;
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
```

An immediate child of this div is:

```
 .my-class {

      position:absolute;
      bottom:6px;
      padding-left:12px;

 }
```

I want the child div to line up with some other content.  Nothing outside of this div is effecting it.  When I use `left:30%` I get one number, when I use `margin-left:30%` I get a different one (which in this case is what I want).

Does margin-left take padding into account and left doesn't?

Or is there some other factor I've not considered?

Comment: A jsfiddle would be nice...

Comment: Both results the same to me - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fLktnb1b/1/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.
Padding is affecting the margin.
Take a look at this example:

```css
div, span {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
}
.left, .marginLeft {
    background: #aaf;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.abs {
    background: #faa;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.left .abs {
    left: 100px;
}
.marginLeft .abs {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Left</h3>
<div class="left">
    parent
    <div class="abs">left</div>
</div>

<h3>Margin left</h3>
<div class="marginLeft">
    parent
    <div class="abs">margin left</div>
</div>
```